# Lucene query - "Match exactly one of x, y, z"

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have a Lucene index that contains documents that have a "type" field, this field can be one of three values "article", "forum" or "blog". I want the user to be able to search within these types (there is a checkbox for each document type)

**How do I create a Lucene query dependent on which types the user has selected?**

A couple of prerequisites are:

- If the user doesn't select one of the types, I want **no** results from that type.
- The ordering of the results should not be affected by restricting the type field.

For reference if I were to write this in SQL (for a "blog or forum search") I'd write:

```
SELECT * FROM Docs
WHERE [type] in ('blog', 'forum')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, should anyone else come across this problem, here is my solution:

```
IList<string> ALL_TYPES = new[] { "article", "blog", "forum" };
string q = ...; // The user's search string
IList<string> includeTypes = ...; // List of types to include
Query searchQuery = parser.Parse(q);
Query parentQuery = new BooleanQuery();
parentQuery.Add(searchQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
// Invert the logic, exclude the other types
foreach (var type in ALL_TYPES.Except(includeTypes))
{
    query.Add(
        new TermQuery(new Term("type", type)),
        BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT
    );
}
searchQuery = parentQuery;
```

I inverted the logic (i.e. excluded the types the user had not selected), because if you don't the ordering of the results is lost. I'm not sure why though...! It is a shame as it makes the code less clear / maintainable, but at least it works!

Answer (score 3):

Add a constraints to reject documents that weren't selected. For example, if only "article" was checked, the constraint would be

```
-(type:forum type:blog)
```

Comment: This is what I did in the end, although I used the API rather than creating it as a string, see my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

While erickson's suggestion seems fine, you could use a positive constraint ANDed with your search term, such as `text:foo AND type:article` for the case only "article" was checked,
or `text:foo AND (type:article OR type:forum)` for the case both "article" and "forum" were checked.

Comment: Intriguingly the two queries "text:foo AND (type:article OR type:forum)" and "text:foo AND -type:blog" do not give the same results, the first query returns the blogs first, where as the second query maintains the ordering (i.e. blogs and articles are mixed). Any idea why?

Comment: Lucene doesn't have an "AND" operator. It has + (require) and - (prohibit) operators.

Comment: @erickson: I beg to differ: e.g. http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR.html